# passing S_POST data to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send a form data using POST method to a PHP page. I want to read that POST value in jquery. Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input name="username" id="username"></input>
  <input type="button"></input>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
<script type="text/javascript">
      alert(<?php $uname ?>);
</script>

$uname = $_POST["username"];
echo $uname;
?>
```

Its not working. 
How can I do the same in an ajax request (instead of a form) like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php", 
    data: {username: $('#username').val()}, 
    success: function(serverResponse){
        $('#Attach').html(serverResponse);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your getting from the alert in alert(<?php $uname ?>);

Answer (score 3):

The bug in your script is you should use echo command in javascript

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      alert('<?php echo $uname; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: +1 to you. Totally glossed over the fact that he's not echoing anything >.<

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the variable is available before you use it.

Once the page is posted to your page

```
<?php
    //after post 
    $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
      alert('<?php echo $uname ?>');
</script>


<?php echo $uname; ?>
```

Comment: yeah, was about to telling the obvious (which perhaps isn't so obvious :P)

Comment: :)
the username is not null... $echo uname is working but not the alert in jquery function.. :(

Comment: @asd did you close the PHP block? Also, you'll need to add quotation marks around the variable. And you need to actually echo it (just added those!) Does firebug give an error?

Comment: @asd: Check my answer, now u will get jquery alert!

Comment: @asd please accept his answer by ticking the big checkmark next to his answer. This marks this question as answered. Please also do the same for the rest of your questions with an answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

use in your Jquery  `alert('<?php $uname ?>');`